# Using columns in lapply with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` with several columns (can be a dynamic number of columns) that I am wanting to apply minimum values to. Each column gets its own specific minimum value.

A basic version of my `data.table` looks like:

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
  urn = 1:10,
  col1 = 5:14,
  col2 = 11:20
)
```

*Note: I've only included two columns with values that need to have minimums for the reprex. There could be more columns, hence trying to code this a little bit dynamically.*

My approach to this has been nested `lapply` statements and so forth, but I can't figure out how to call my column within my `lapply` function.

```
min_vals <- c(10, 15)
my_cols <- grep("^col", colnames(dt), value = TRUE)

## First approach
dt[,
  (my_cols) := lapply(min_vals, function(x) {
    my_cols[my_cols < x] <- x
  })]

## Second Approach
dt[,
  (my_cols) := lapply(min_vals, function(x) {
    ifelse(my_cols < x, x, my_cols)
  })]
```

At the moment the first approach sets all rows to the respective `min_vals`, rather than just the values below the `min_vals`. The second approach doesn't work at all, but instead errors.

The desired output looks like the following:

```
dt
#       urn  col1  col2
#     <int> <int> <int>
#  1:     1    10    15
#  2:     2    10    15
#  3:     3    10    15
#  4:     4    10    15
#  5:     5    10    15
#  6:     6    10    16
#  7:     7    11    17
#  8:     8    12    18
#  9:     9    13    19
# 10:    10    14    20
```

It would be great to have a solution that allows for a dynamic numner of columns that match the `col<number>` format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could use `Map` instead of `lapply` and, as @Roland in the comments points out, i) loop over `.SD` as first input (specifying `.SDcols` with `mycols`) and use ii) the faster `fielse` instead of `ifelse`.

```r
library(data.table)

dt[, (my_cols) := Map(\(x, m) fifelse(x < m, m, x),
                      .SD,
                      min_vals),
   .SDcols = my_cols]

dt
#>     urn col1 col2
#>  1:   1   10   15
#>  2:   2   10   15
#>  3:   3   10   15
#>  4:   4   10   15
#>  5:   5   10   15
#>  6:   6   10   16
#>  7:   7   11   17
#>  8:   8   12   18
#>  9:   9   13   19
#> 10:  10   14   20
```

@Mwavu suggests another great option using `pmax` instead of `fifelse` in the comments:

```r
dt[, c(my_cols) := Map(\(x, y) pmax(x, y), .SD, min_vals), .SDcols = my_cols]
#> same result as above
```

Data from OP

```
dt <- data.table(
  urn = 1:10,
  col1 = 5:14,
  col2 = 11:20
)

min_vals <- c(10, 15)
my_cols <- grep("^col", colnames(dt), value = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You don't need `get` and you should switch to `fifelse`: `dt[, (my_cols) := Map(\(x, m) fifelse(x < m, m, x), .SD, min_vals), .SDcols = my_cols]`

Comment: `DT[, c(my_cols) := Map(\(x, y) pmax(x, y), .SD, min_vals), .SDcols = my_cols]`

Answer (score 3):

Here you're actually trying to loop through two lists/vectors at once which lapply isn't designed to do. So here `mapply` would be useful:

```r
library("data.table")

dt <- data.table(urn = 1:10,
                 col1 = 5:14,
                 col2 = 11:20)

min_vals <- c(10, 15)
my_cols <- grep("^col", colnames(dt), value = TRUE)

dt[,
   (my_cols) := mapply(function(x, y) {
     ifelse(x < y, y, x)
   },
   x = .SD,
   y = min_vals,
   SIMPLIFY = FALSE), .SDcols = my_cols]
```

To make sure you apply your function only to the columns you want, you also need to tell it to subset the data to only keep the columns you want (`.SD` is the subset of your data containing the columns in `my_cols`).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `set()`:

```
for(i in seq_along(min_vals)) set(dt,which(my_cols[i]<min_vals[i]), my_cols[i]<min_vals[i], min_vals[i])
```

Output:

```
      urn  col1  col2
    <int> <int> <int>
 1:     1    10    15
 2:     2    10    15
 3:     3    10    15
 4:     4    10    15
 5:     5    10    15
 6:     6    10    16
 7:     7    11    17
 8:     8    12    18
 9:     9    13    19
10:    10    14    20
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *forloop*:

```
for(i in seq_along(min_vals)){
  dt[ get(my_cols[ i ]) < min_vals[ i ], (my_cols[ i ]) := min_vals[ i ] ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With all the answers that came in I wanted to see which one was faster.

```
  library(data.table)
  library(microbenchmark)
  microbenchmark(
    for_loop = {
      for (i in seq_along(min_vals)) {
        dt[get(my_cols[i]) < min_vals[i], (my_cols[i]) := min_vals[i]]
      }
    },
    for_loop_set = {
      for (i in seq_along(min_vals)) {
        set(dt, which(my_cols[i] < min_vals[i]), my_cols[i] < min_vals[i], min_vals[i])
      }
    },
    Map_fifelse = {
      dt[, (my_cols) := Map(
        \(x, m) fifelse(x < m, m, x),
        .SD,
        min_vals),
        .SDcols = my_cols]
    },
    Map_pmap = {
      dt[, c(my_cols) := Map(
        \(x, y) pmax(x, y),
        .SD,
        min_vals),
        .SDcols = my_cols]
    },
    mapply = {
      dt[, (my_cols) := mapply(function(x, y) {
          ifelse(x < y, y, x)
        },
        x = .SD,
        y = min_vals,
        SIMPLIFY = FALSE), 
        .SDcols = my_cols]
    },
    setup = {
      dt <- data.table(
        urn = 1:10000,
        col1 = 1:10000,
        col2 = floor((1:10000) * 1.5),
        col3 = floor((1:10000) * 2)
      )
      min_vals <- c(10, 15, 20)
      my_cols <- grep("^col", colnames(dt), value = TRUE) 
    }
  )
```

The `Map` function certainly appears to yield the quickest results on a dataset with 10K records. `pmap` and `fifelse` are quite similar in performance.

```
Unit: microseconds
         expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
     for_loop 3801.518 3905.0950 4389.2638 4015.9215 4142.7935 8177.223   100
 for_loop_set 3087.890 3158.1060 3637.1434 3222.1815 3358.5935 8222.822   100
  Map_fifelse  439.376  456.0745  494.7738  471.6495  527.2700  717.605   100
     Map_pmap  454.653  465.9865  492.4828  476.6925  492.1330  705.034   100
       mapply  745.789  764.0405  869.2662  775.5225  810.0075 5093.581   100
```